# how to dynamically define a menu item - what is the thing in square braces?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Not clear on some fundamental syntax here. `define-key` accepts a set of inputs, one of which is inside square braces. What is that construct?  How can I dynamically generate what goes inside the square braces?

In the simple case, I can display a one-item menu like this:

```
(flet ((ok (&optional p1 &rest args) t))
  (setq menu-1 (make-sparse-keymap "Title"))
  (define-key menu-1 [menu-1-ok-event]
    `(menu-item "OK"
                ok 
                :keys ""
                :visible t
                :enable t))
  (x-popup-menu t menu-1))
```

I can insert additional menu items like this:

```
(flet ((ok (&optional p1 &rest args) t))
  (setq menu-1 (make-sparse-keymap "Title"))
  (define-key menu-1 [menu-1-event-ok]
    `(menu-item "OK"
                ok 
                :keys ""
                :visible t
                :enable t))
  (define-key menu-1 [menu-1-event-1]
    `(menu-item "This is line 1"
                nil
                :keys ""
                :visible t
                :enable t))
  (x-popup-menu t menu-1))
```

But what if I want to dynamically generate the thing inside square braces?  What if I want something like this:

```
  (while (< n 5)
   (define-key menu-1 [(dynamic-thing n)]
    `(menu-item (format "This is line %d" n)
                nil
                :keys ""
                :visible t
                :enable t)))
```

I tried

```
   (define-key menu-1 [(intern (format "menu-1-event-%d" n))]
      ...
```

..but that did not work. The result is always "intern". ???

What are the square braces? The syntax is unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [vectors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Vectors.html#Vectors). `[foo bar]` is syntactic sugar for `(quote (vector foo bar))`; it's a literal. To construct a vector where the elements need to be evaluated, use the [`vector`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Vector-Functions.html#index-vector-403) built-in function explicitly; it works like `list`.

```
(define-key menu-1 (vector (format "menu-1-event-%d" n)) …
```

The chapter on [menu keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Menu-Keymaps.html#Menu-Keymaps) may help as well.